# A way to avoid repetitive codes tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to display images using tkinter. I notice that there are repetitive codes here. I am trying to get rid of these codes to display images. My goal is to display a number of images not in a discrete way but to display them dynamically in quantities.

please help thank you.

```
def __init__(self):
    Frame.__init__(self)
    self.master.title("Black Jack")
    blackjack = Blackjack()
    self.grid()

    self._playerCardImage = PhotoImage(file=str(blackjack._player._cards[0].fileName))
    self._playerCardLabel = Label(self, image = self._playerCardImage)
    self._playerCardLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)


    self._playerCardImage1 = PhotoImage(file=str(blackjack._player._cards[1].fileName))
    self._playerCardLabel1 = Label(self, image = self._playerCardImage1)
    self._playerCardLabel1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    self._dealerCardImage = PhotoImage(file=str(blackjack._dealer._cards[0].fileName))
    self._dealerCardLabel = Label(self, image = self._dealerCardImage)
    self._dealerCardLabel.grid(row=0, column=2)

    self._dealerCardImage1 = PhotoImage(file=str(blackjack._dealer._cards[1].fileName))
    self._dealerCardLabel1 = Label(self, image = self._dealerCardImage1)
    self._dealerCardLabel1.grid(row=0, column=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what your pattern is, but if it's what I suspect, the below should work:

```
for index in range(<your range>):
    if index % 4 == 0:
        self._playerCardImage = PhotoImage(file=str(blackjack._player._cards[index].fileName))
        self._playerCardLabel = Label(self, image = self._playerCardImage)
        self._playerCardLabel.grid(row=0, column=index)

    elsif index %4 == 1:
        self._playerCardImage1 = PhotoImage(file=str(blackjack._player._cards[index].fileName))
        self._playerCardLabel1 = Label(self, image = self._playerCardImage1)
        self._playerCardLabel1.grid(row=0, column=index)
    ...
```

You should be able to calculate the row/column/file index using the mod operation on the index variable. If there are only four branches (as in your example above), you'll have four branches in your if statement.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried that way but the Label refreshes and display images only the last one. :(

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem is the use of the variable `playerCardImage/Label`. You need to append the index to the variable name like so: `val = getattr(self, 'playerCardImage' + str(index)` for each of the attributes you're assigning.